# Magento2 what is use of canRestore property in system.xml?

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml, system-configuration

Can anyone let me know what is exact use of canRestore property defined in system.xml field in Magento2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using config.xml we set default values for configuration in of the module. so **canRestore** is used to reset the field to the default value which specified in config.xml.

This will appear as checkbox in admin. You can show Use system value check-box to system configuration by **canRestore="1"** property in system.xml